# Differences between SAS and SQL

Tags: sql, sas

Can anyone articulate what the key differences are between SAS and SQL? I haven't worked much with SAS but went on a weeks training course, and basically it seemed like the equivalent but more convoluted and was able to do graphs.

Would appreciate some key bullet differences between them.

Comment: Check https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-performance-benchmarks-on-PROC-SQL-SAS-vs-SQL

Comment: SQL is a database management language. SAS is for statistical analysis, where data management is required as a prerequisite.

Comment: SQL is a language standard, supported by database vendors (and others).  SAS is a complex software system, as well as a company based in Cary, NC.  Buried deep within the SAS system is `proc SQL`, which supports a variant of the SQL language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard SQL is a language to query, manipulate and define data in any(!) database. It is like the "latin language" of DB systems. Everyone knows it in order to perform standard tasks. SAS is like an extension to that with many functions.

I found a good document:
http://www.sascommunity.org/mwiki/images/5/52/CMSSUG-0506-SQL.pdf